# Sending info to UIImageView event handler

Tags: uiimageview, swift3

I'm populating UIImageViews dynamic and have to send some info (at least index: Int) to handler of press event. I've done this before with UIButton easy, while UIButton has a tag property, but how I can do it with UIImageView?

Answer (score 0):

The [tag property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag) on UIButton is inherited from UIView.  That means UIImageView also has a tag property because it too inherits from UIView.